# Angular ng-repeat use ng-if

Tags: angularjs, laravel

Exceuse me, 
my angular get two array value

I want to if house value id = hosue_img value house_id ,then show house_img value.

then I want to show like this code

```
@foreach($house as $value)
  <?php $check = 0; $ok;?>
  @foreach($house_img as $va)
    @if($va->house_id == $value->id)
    <?php
          $check = 1;
          $ok = $va->house_img;
    ?>
      @break
    @endif
  @endforeach

  @if($check == 1)
    <img src="{{asset('house_img/')}}/{{$ok}}" >
  @endif
@endforeach
```

but I change angular.js is not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         var check = 0;
         var ok;
</script>
<div ng-repeat="house in houses">
  <div ng-repeat="img in house_imgs">
    <section ng-if="house.id == img.house_id">
       <script type="text/javascript">
           check = 1;
           ok = img.house_img;
       </script>
    </section>
  </div>

  <div ng-if="check == 1">
      <img src="{{asset('house_img/')}}/@{{ok}}" >
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I do, please~  thank you~

Comment: try to put you javascript code in a separate file, it not readable at all.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using angular, you should so operations in your controller

```
angular.forEach($scope.houses, function(house) {
    angular.forEach($scope.house_imgs, function(img) {
        if ( img.house_id === house.id ) { 
            check = 1
            ok = img.house_img
        }
    })
})
```

This is assuming `var check` and `var ok` are already defined.
If you really want to set it in the view you can replace the `<script></script>` part with `{{ check=1;"" }}`.

Since you are mixing laravel and angular, you will have to change angular braces interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

if you doesn't want to display any data by ng-repeat you need to check condition inside the controller and assign the img according to condtion. like as

Html

```
<div ng-if="check == 1">
      <img src="{{asset('house_img/')}}/@{{ok}}" >
  </div>
```

inside the Controller

```
$scope.check = 0;
$scope.ok = '';
angular.forEach(houses, function(house, key) {
  angular.forEach(house_imgs, function(image, key) {
  if(houses.id == image.house_id) {
      $scope.check = 1;
      $scope.ok = image.house_img;
}
});
});
```